# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type... when using a function which requires type string

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm doing an Angular with express backend aplication. The backend gives me a response like this

console.log(res) -->

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "msg": "Login ok",
    "auth": "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

Now that i have my response i'm trying to save it in a localStorage

```
localStorage.setItem('auth', res['auth']); //also tried res.get('auth');
```

However setItem receives string as first element, and **string as second element** and i keep getting the following error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type ""auth"" cannot be used to index type "Object".

Comment: What is `res`? I'm not sure, but it looks like a `string` in JSON format, not an indexable JS/TS object. If so, you'd want to let Angular deserialize it into an object before you try to access it like that. See Gabriel's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an interface and set your backend response type to it like so :

```
export interface BackEndResponse{
    ok: boolean;
    message: string;
    auth: string;
}
```

I don't know how you're querying your backend but here is an example subscribing to the method that makes the request and return the object as an observable,

```
setLocalStorage(): void {
    this.yourBackEndService.getBackEndInfo().subscribe((backEndResponse) => {
      localStorage.setItem('auth', backEndResponse.auth);
      // ...
    });
  }
```